# Slide Carousel without Manipulating DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on my custom carousel slider and I want to make it slide left/right infinitely. When I click on next button, it should slide toward left. Right now when I reach to the last item and next button is pressed, I take the first item and append that to the last before sliding left.

```
$(".carousel-inner").find("div:last").after($(".carousel-inner").find("div:first"));
```

I am supposed to do it **without changing DOM**. Is there any good logic to loop infinitely?

Comment: [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) is what I found which might work. If you want to program it yourself, you could look in the code I guess.

Comment: There is bunch of code man. I just need the idea behind this infinite rotation and I will write code by my own following that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap. It's quite easy to use and won't manipulate the DOM. Moreover, basic functionality doesn't even require you to write any javascript. Example of how to use is [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#example).